# Is a snide comment rude or just unnecessary?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

I often find myself unable to decide between "rude" and "unnecessary" flag reasons, as it isn't uncommon for unnecessary comments to also be pot shots at new users.

I recently flagged a comment that was overly critical of an OP called "Hacker". It basically said:

> Are you sure your name should be HACKER if you don't even understand the basics?

I flagged it as NLN because it didn't add anything of value to the question. The comment ended up being removed, so evidently a mod agreed with it.

Really though, now I'm wondering if it should have been flagged as rude, because it certainly strikes me as an attempt to be rude.

Does it even matter though? A mod looked at it regardless, and acted. Is this something I should spend time mulling over, or just flag with either and move on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can certainly flag those comments as rude/abusive, because they violate the [Be Nice](/help/be-nice) policy:

> Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.

Of course, No Longer Needed applies as well; that comment was never needed in the first place.